# Why is the user's name appearing as blank in the backendless console with Facebook SDK login for an Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, backendless

Here is my code for the login Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private Button facebookButton;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.login );

    initUI();

    Backendless.setUrl( Defaults.SERVER_URL );
    Backendless.initApp( this, Defaults.APPLICATION_ID, Defaults.SECRET_KEY, Defaults.VERSION );

    Backendless.UserService.isValidLogin( new DefaultCallback<Boolean>( this )
    {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse( Boolean isValidLogin )
        {
            if( isValidLogin && Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser() == null )
            {
                String currentUserId = Backendless.UserService.loggedInUser();

                if( !currentUserId.equals( "" ) )
                {
                    Backendless.UserService.findById( currentUserId, new DefaultCallback<BackendlessUser>( LoginActivity.this, "Logging in..." )
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser currentUser )
                        {
                            super.handleResponse( currentUser );
                            Backendless.UserService.setCurrentUser( currentUser );
                            startActivity( new Intent( getBaseContext(), LoginSuccessActivity.class ) );
                            finish();
                        }
                    } );
                }
            }

            super.handleResponse( isValidLogin );
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
    editor.commit();

}

private void initUI()
{
    facebookButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.loginFacebookButton );

    facebookButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view )
        {
            onLoginWithFacebookButtonClicked();
        }
    } );
}

public void onLoginWithFacebookButtonClicked()
{
    Backendless.UserService.loginWithFacebook( LoginActivity.this, new SocialCallback<BackendlessUser>( LoginActivity.this )
    {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser backendlessUser )
        {
            startActivity( new Intent( getBaseContext(), LoginSuccessActivity.class ) );
            finish();
        }
    } );
}
```

However, after a successful login, the Backendless console doesn't show the name of the user. I don't think there are any syntactical errors in my code, I must just be missing something.

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mappings between the Facebook fields and your table's fields. This is described in the documentation: https://backendless.com/documentation/users/android/users_facebook_login.htm